# Master Detail breaks parameters?

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

I don't need a MasterDetail until I've navigated through two regular ContentPages first, where I collect information that the MasterDetail will need. The ContentPages make use of the INavigationParameters sent to OnNavigatedTo and OnNavigatedFrom for that collected information.

The the SecondPage viewmodel handles a button command wherein the handler calls the MasterDetail:

> NavigationService.NavigateAsync("CompareSelectionsMasterDetail/CompareSelectionsNavigationPage/RangeCircle",
>   parameters);

Sure enough, the RangeCircleViewModel.OnNavigatedTo receives the parameters. However, when I go back (like with the Android back button), its OnNavigatedFrom is **not called**, thereby sending null parameters back leaving my ContentPages with no idea what their state was.

The viewmodel for CompareSelectionMasterDetail doesn't do anything and the viewmodel for CompareSelectionsNavigationPage just does this:

> ```
> public class CompareSelectionsNavigationPage : NavigationPage, INavigationPageOptions
> {
>     public bool ClearNavigationStackOnNavigation => false;
> }
> ```
>
> I'm not sure what it means to have a NavigationPage in the MasterDetailPage XAML and the separate CompareSelectionsNavigationPage that I call with Prism but if I remove the XAML one, the RangeCircle page doesn't render. If I only have the XAML one and change the Prism navigation to CompareSelectionsMasterDetail/NavigationPage/RangeCircle then I get the same behavior as using both NavigationPages.

My MasterDetail XAML is simple.

```
> <MasterDetailPage.Master>
>     <NavigationPage Title="Required Foo" Icon="hamburger_icon.png">
>         <x:Arguments>
>             <ContentPage Title="Menu">
>                 <StackLayout Padding="40">
>                     <!-- TODO: // Update the Layout and add some real menu items  -->
>                     <Label Text="Hello John"/>
>                     <Button Text="Range Circle" Command="{Binding NavigateToRangeCircleCommand}" CommandParameter="ViewA" />
>                 </StackLayout>
>             </ContentPage>
>         </x:Arguments>
>     </NavigationPage> </MasterDetailPage.Master>
```

Every example I can find of Master Detail (especially with Prism) starts off the app with Master Detail page. I'm not sure if my usage is what breaks OnNavigatedFrom? (Basically ContentPage(Page1)->ContentPage(Page2)->MasterDetail->NavigationPage->NavigationPage->ContentPage(RangeCircle))

The individual ContentPages don't have a problem calling OnNavigatedFrom.

Comment: I don't know if I mean correctly but you want to have eg. login page as ContentPage and after correct login do you want to load master detail ?

Comment: So you are telling me that for eg: You have three pages A, B and C so you start off with A > B where A and B are content pages, then from B you navigate to C which is a master-detail page. Now you want to go back to C from B is it? And when you do that the page C is empty?

Comment: G.hakim that is correct. The OnNavigatedFrom of C (or for that matter any of the detail pages of C) is not getting called. This means I cannot package up the necessary parameters on the way back to B so B doesn't know what its state was.

Comment: qubuss, that is not quite right. My app won't have a login. The first two pages are collecting options that the Master Detail needs to drive its detail pages.